# Rear derailleur is messed up

Tags: derailleur-rear

I have no clue what happened to my derailleur on my bike. I can ride the bike and after a couple of cranks the chain gets really lose and seems like it's about to come off so I stop pedaling and wait and then the tire does a couple of rotations and the chains tight again.
[image]

Comment: It sounds like you have chain suck. Are your cogs/chainrings wornout?

Comment: No my cog and chain are in good shape

Comment: Hey I have a pic how do I put it up on here

Comment: theres an image button in the editor. It'll upload the image to imgur and then display it.

Comment: I still have no clue where that is.

Comment: My rear derailleur  is horizontal instead of vertical and it just happened after I was doing wheelies

Comment: How do I fix the chain suck if that the case.

Comment: @Vitaly the image button is here: http://imgur.com/qkajYEM . Press the "edit" button below the question body to get there.

Comment: It's not letting me

Comment: i think new users might not have image permission. you can upload the images to a gallery at imgur.com and then put a link in there though. then someone can edit them into the post.

Comment: I just added it

Comment: I had to go on the full site couldn't add it on there mobile site

Comment: It's quite pixellated. Is the chain on the smallest cog or is it jammed between the smallest cog and the frame or what? Where is the chain in the front?

Comment: The chain is on the smallest cog and it's on the first cog in the front

Comment: Looks like too much chain to me.  Notice the derailleur is maxed on taking up chain.

Comment: So I'm supposed to shorten the chain and that should fix the problem

Comment: Have you always had this problem, or did it start after some period (months?) of reasonably good operation?  If it "just started", was any maintenance done on the bike prior to that?  (This sounds most like "chain suck" due to worn cogs.)

Comment: I'm guessing the photo is with the chain in small/small, so that's the most spare chain you can have.  Its right on the limit of "acceptable", because the chain doesn't look to touch itself going around the jockey wheels.  Try changing gear to big/big and take the same photo again, that'll help.

Answer (score 1):

Chain looks too long to me.  Shorten the chain.

Not gong to guarantee that will fix the problem but it looks like part of the problem to me.

[Park Chain Sizing](http://www.parktool.com/blog/repair-help/chain-length-sizing#article-section-1)

[Park chain cutting](http://www.parktool.com/blog/repair-help/chain-installation-derailleur-bikes#article-section-7)

Comment: When I just got the bike it was normal until I started to do wheelies and then that's what happened to my rear derailleur

Comment: You mean it looks to long not short

Comment: Come on down vote what is the problem?

Comment: @Frisbee Wasn't me. Next time you complain about downvotes I'm gonna downvote too.

Comment: @BSOrider That was a question.